# Finiteness for 2-dimensional contractible complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, operads

While thinking about graph-complex and related operadic stuff, I found a quite interesting (at least for me) question. However, I'm a novice in the algebraic topology, so I'm unable to resolve it by myself.

**Definition** Let us call a (pure) $n$-dimensional polyhedral complex the topological space glued from a finite number of $n$-dimensional (convex) polyhedra by faces. We will not remember the structure of gluing in what follows.

**Note** As any polyhedron can be dissected into simplices, it is, probably, the same as a semisimplicial set (generated by its top simplices).

**Note** I also have in mind an additional condition/tweak but not sure whether I need it: "removal of codimension 2 facets doesn't disconnect the complex".

**Definition** The boundary of a complex is defined as a union of codimension $1$ faces contained only in a single top-dimensional polyhedron.

**Note** This notion seems to be well-defined on a level of a topological space (closure of the locus of points admitting a neighborhood homeomorphic to the $n$-dimensional half-space).

**Example** $1$-dimensional complex is naturally a graph without vertices of index $2$. Its vertices of index $1$ (leafs) are the boundary.

It is well known that there is a finite number of trees with the fixed set of leafs. I'm trying to generalise it as follows:

EDIT: Turns out that this question has negative answer:
**For a given graph $\Gamma$ without boundary, is there a finite number of topological types (up to homeomorphism) of a** *contractible* **$2$-dimensional complexes with the boundary $\Gamma$?**
EDIT: And it is better to ask about collapsable complexes rather than contractible ones.

**Note** We consider $2$-complexes up to homeomorphism, but different cellular decompositions of the same space are still identified (otherwise even a $2$-disk will have an infinite number of decompositions).

**Note** The answer to analogous $1$-dimensional question is "yes", because there is only finite number of trees (without vertices of index $2$) with the prescribed set of leaves.

My (geometric) intuition says that the answer is "yes" in this case too, but its probably because I'm thinking about embedded complexes, not "real" ones. Also, knowing how hard might be the questions about $2$-dimensional complexes (say, Whitehead hypothesis), I'm really not sure whether the fact is true or not.

Comment: There is only one contractible homotopy type. What do you mean by the "topological type"?

Comment: I mean non-homeomorphic as a topological spaces. Thx for the comment, I will add it in the question.

The 1-dimensional example I have in mind is trees - there is a finite number of trees with a fixed set of leaves.

Comment: This is already false for $\Gamma$ which is empty as there are infinitely many homeomorphism types of contractible noncollapsable 2-complexes.

Comment: Thank you! This is a particular answer. (also I wonder, what could be said about collapsable complexes)?